# TYPO3 Lost templates after importing website

Tags: templates, typo3

I developed a typo3 website (TYPO3 v 6.1.3) on my local server. Importing it to my webserver I ran into this problem: After the end of the import process I see all the templates in the Template Analyzer. But when I start to correct anything (for example the baseUrl in the root template) all the templates disappear in the Template Analyzer and I get the following error message in the frontend:

```
#1301648167: The requested page didn't have a proper connection to the tree-root!<br /><br />()
```

The requested page has the uid of the root page.

Thanks for any help
Georg

Comment: This error is sometimes triggered by a shortcut in the page tree which points to no page or something like that.

Comment: I checked that and the two shortcuts to the root page are fine (it's a two domain website with one tree) - Georg

Comment: Do you have realURL running? If so, I would clear all the caches including realURL caches, uninstall it completely and see if the error persists. Then, reinstall & eventually reconfigure realURL

Comment: Can you explain, how you imported the data into your webserver? T3D / Copy & Paste / MySQLDump? Did you cleared the cache? Did you truncated all Caching Framework (cf_*) tables?

Comment: Thanks for your questions and hints: I don't use realURL but coolURI; I imported the data by MSQLDump using phpmyadmin; I cleared the Caching Framework several times and deleted all files in the typo3temp folder. Maybe it's helpful to know that I want to migrate the installation from templavoila to backend layout and grid elements. I uninstalled Templavoila and Static Info Tables and installed Grid Elements  - Georg

Comment: I finally solved the problem by doing a comparision of the tables in the install tool. It had something to do with the colPos field of the tt_content table. (Unfortunately I didn't read it carefully enough to say it precisely here). After that I had lost all relations between the gridelements and the content elements but could see all pages in the frontend again. Thanks for your help - Georg